# t.v.+to+v analysis

Tags: grammatical-roles

> I desire to receive the prize money.
>
> I dared to fool my teacher.
>
> I failed to persuade him.

The main verbs become intransitive verbs. The to-infinitives serve as adverbials.
Does this analysis exist?

Comment: You might need to elaborate: how do the main verbs function as adverbials in your examples?

Answer (score 1):

They are all infinitive phrases acting as noun phrases and the object of the transitive verbs.

https://englishsentences.com/infinitive-phrase/

> a. Infinitive Phrase as a Noun
>
> When an infinitive phrase works like a noun, it answers the question “what?” So, the infinitive phrase will be the subject, which does the verb; or an object, which receives the action of the verb. Here are some examples:

```
>I don’t want to study for my test. What don’t you want? (Object)
>He needs to ace the exam. What does he need? (Object)
>To get good grades is my goal. What is the goal? (Subject)
>His job was to tutor me in math. What was his job? (Object)
```